# Google Charts plotting variable against time

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-visualization

thanks in advance for looking at this!

I am looking to plot latency values against time in a django web application. The data for 'time' and 'latency' is coming from a MySQL database. My problem with googlecharts is dissimilar to most, as I need convert python strings like this:

```
'2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45'
```

Into Javascript datetime objects which are like this:

```
new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)
```

Each time the page refreshes the recent data must be read from the database and converted from a string to JavaScript datetime object, and then encoded in Json in this format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"label":"Time","type":"datetime"},
        {"label":"Latency","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"},{"v":3}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"},{"v":2}]}
      ]
}
```

This file is read in javascript and the data within is passed to the chart for drawing.

I'm getting caught up in how to generate the javascript datetime object from a python string, as well as formatting the output of the json encoder to the format above.

I have scoured stack overflow and the Google Charts API but i cant find a solution. If there is someone who solved this problem or has experience of reading a database and producing a Google Line Chart from the read data, I'd be extremely grateful if you could point me in the right direction!

Thanks again.

Comment: Using the DataTable JSON structure, you want to remove the "new" keyword from the Date strings, eg: `"new Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"` should be `"Date(2014, 12, 31, 14, 2, 45)"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @asgallant, I'll make the ammendments and see if I can get it working!